# How to start activity from background service

Tags: android

I have a VoIP application that after it's being swept away from recent apps should show an activity when I receive the call. There is a background service that should create this activity, but after swiping the app away that's not possible.

So, how to start activity from background service in this case?

Comment: Where are you creating and starting the service?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a UI thread Handler.
Just do this in Activity class:

```
private final Handler h = new Handler();
```

Then, pass this handler to background service, and do next:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         //startActivity
       }

   });
```

Read about handler [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
Handler, is such as message queue of thread. You just post message to queue, and it will be processed as soon as possible